# how to decrypt a string that is encrypted using XOR

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, xor

I have tried to encrypt a string using a XOR operator and took the output in alphabets. Now when I am trying to decrypt it I'm not getting the string again.
Encryption code:

```
string= "Onions"
keyword = "MELLON"

def xor(string, key):
    st=[]
    ke=[]
    xored=[]

    for i in string:
        asc= (ord(i))
        st.append(int(asc))
    print(st)

    for i in key:
        asc= (ord(i))
        ke.append(int(asc))
    print(ke)

    for i in range(len(string)):
        s1=st[i]
        k1=ke[i]
        abc = s1^k1
        le = ord('A')+abc
        ch = chr(le)
        if le> 90:
            le= le-26
            ch = chr(le)
        print(s1,k1)
        print('XOR =',abc)
        print(ch)
        xored.append(ch)
    print(xored)
    return("" . join(xored))
```

Need help!!

Comment: what if string is not the same length as keyword?

Comment: In this part, I just tried to encrypt using XOR by keeping things as simple as possible. I have covered this problem in another part of the code(which I have not mentioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm does not perform a pure XOR, but maps values *conditionally* to another value, leading to a relation that is no longer [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).

To illustrate this point. See what this script outputs:

```
keyword = "MELLON"
print(xor("Onions", keyword) == xor("OTGEHs", keyword))
```

It will output `True`!

So this means you have two words that are encrypted to the *same* string. This also means that if you  need to do the reverse, there is no way to know which of these is the real original word.

If you want to decryption to be possible, make sure to only use operations that lead to a bijective mapping. For instance, if you only use a XOR, without adding or subtracting values, it will be OK.

Here is an approach where only lower and uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet are allowed (for both arguments):

```
def togglecrypt(string, key):
    mapper = "gUMtuAqhaEDcsGjBbreSNJYdFTiOmHKwnXWxzClQLRVyvIkfPpoZ"

    res = []
    for i, ch in enumerate(string):
        shift = mapper.index(key[i % len(key)]) % 26
        i = mapper.index(ch)
        if i < 26:
            j = 26 + (i + shift) % 26
        else:
            j = (i - shift) % 26
        res.append(mapper[j])
    return("".join(res))

keyword = "MELLON"
encoded = togglecrypt("Onions", keyword)
print(encoded)  # TdsDAn
print(togglecrypt(encoded, keyword))  # Onions
```

Comment: In that case, I will not get alphabets in output. Is there any way to get output in alphabets? Because I want to use the encrypted text in another part of the code.

Comment: That is a new question?

Comment: An emerging one .... can say

Comment: Added a possible solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you for the help.